# How can I send multiple binary UDP packets from a single file using netcat?

Tags: netcat

Is there a delimiter or some way of telling netcat how many bytes to send per packet from a file? Invoking netcat multiple times in a script is not acceptable as I need to send them out as fast as possible.

I have captured UDP packets with binary data into a file using mnc (multicast netcat) and attempt to play them back as follows:

start program sending multicast packets to 230.250.5.1 12340

... start mnc to capture packets:

```
$mnc -l -i eth1 -p 12340 230.250.5.1 >capturefile
```

... playback packets using netcat, sending to 230.250.5.1 12345

```
$netcat -c -w 1 -u -s 10.20.30.40 230.250.5.1 12345 <capturefile
```

capturefile appears to have the packets I want to send.

When I play back with netcat the packets are concatenated. UDP packet size is 208 during packet capture and wireshark shows 250 as packet size, I assume that includes ethernet bytes. On replay, wireshark shows packet size of 1016.